# Is it ok to remove Google TXT verification records after I've authorized my domain with Google?

Tags: dns, google-analytics, bing, google-search-console

For Google Analytics, I had to prove that I owned my domain. I added a TXT record to do this. I also had to prove to Microsoft that I owned my domain by uploading a file (BingSiteAuth.xml) to my site.

Now that I'm up and running with Analytics and Webmaster tools for Google and Bing, can I remove these verification records, or will that break analytics? Does leaving the record and file there pose any kind of security risk?

Comment: Why was this closed? It's a valid question with a definite answer... Maybe this should have been moved to a different SE website?

Comment: Yes, "Webmasters" or "Server Fault" would have been a better place for this question.

Comment: Ok, can we reopen it and move it to webmasters? Mainly because it might help others...

Comment: You can try to flag the question, select "it needs moderator attention", and ask if it can be moved.

Comment: I just voted to re-open so this question can be migrated to the Pro Webmasters SE site.

Comment: Voted to re-open, to be moved.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No, you shouldn't remove any of the verification files or DNS records. Google will periodically recheck your site and if it doesn't succeed you will lose access to WMT, for example. See [this WMT support page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176792):

> Removing the record from your server can cause your site to become
>   unverified, and you will need to go through the verification process
>   again.

I'm not 100% sure but I think Bing will do the same. It makes sense because a domain owner or the roles of administrators might change and you don't want anyone who ever had access to your site's data to keep that access right forever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ok, one more question. For Bing, I used the xml file method. Can I switch it to use the DNS record method? That way I don't accidentally wipe it out?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to change verification methods for Bing.

Comment: Yes, I was able to change it. I think I prefer to have the verification stuff done at the DNS level. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The accepted response may no longer be accurate. The provided snippet is no longer visible on that page. Also, I just spoke with a Google support rep via chat and they assured me that it's not necessary to keep the TXT record after verification, but they were unable to point me to any docs, which I would've shared here :(

Comment: Verifying ownership in Google's Webmaster Central has this message when verifying via a TXT record: "To stay verified, don't remove the DNS record, even after verification succeeds."